# Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint - How can I avoid inserting changed data with same PK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automationstudio

I'm having an issue with a primary key violation that is a little different than others posted.  I have a Contact, who can have one or more Reservations.  I need to pull a list for a Journey very early in the morning because data may change and I send it to a DE for further processing the next day.  As Contacts can have multiple Reservations, I PARTITION BY the contact.id.

However, the Check Out date can change, and when that happens, I get a primary key conflict (Which is based on the Reservation.id).  (Say Check Out was 1/1/2021, I capture that in the DE, and later that day they decide to stay another night, so check out becomes 1/2/2021.  Now when this runs on 1/2, I have a PK conflict as they are already in the DE from the 1/1/2021 stay.)

```sql
SELECT  
    ReservationID, 
    Salutation,
    FirstName,  
    LastName, 
    ContactID,
    CheckOut, 
    Email
FROM (    
SELECT reservation.Id as ReservationID, 
    reservation.Check_Out__c as CheckOut,
    contact.Salutation as Salutation,  
    contact.FirstName as FirstName,  
    contact.LastName as LastName, 
    contact.id as ContactID,
    contact.email, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY contact.id ORDER BY reservation.ExternalId__c DESC) as ID_Row
from Reservation__c_Salesforce reservation
INNER JOIN
    Contact_Salesforce contact on contact.id = reservation.Contact__c
WHERE reservation.Check_Out__c = CONVERT(Date, GETUTCDATE())
  AND reservation.ID NOT IN (select reservationId from Journey_DE)
  ) as A
WHERE ID_Row = 1
```

This automation runs to populate the Journey_DE, so I tried adding:

`AND reservation.ID NOT IN (select reservationId from Journey_DE)`

but it seems to have no effect.  In this case I just want to ignore that record.

Any ideas are appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to violate the PK, you'll need to include all of the PK fields in your partition.  If the PK of the target DE has more than `contactID`, then I'd expect it to fail.

Comment: Do as @AdamSpriggs say or you can set the query to 'Update' instead to 'Append', doing so it will update the row (if there is one with the same Primary Key) instead of trying to add a new one

Comment: Thank you both.  I can't find a way to avoid this situation using partition by, so I've opted to use 'Update' instead of 'Append'.  So far, so good.  Thanks again!